# Comparing int8_t and char* using strcmp/strncmp

Tags: c, pointers, char, strcmp, strncmp

Currently trying to fix code that was left unused for a while.

I have two variables: `int8_t foo[size]` and `const char* const bar`.

There is an if that checks `if(0 != strcmp((char *)foo, bar))`

Currently this is failing even though `printf("%s | %s", foo, bar)` returns two strings the exact same. I also tried `strncmp` which is also failing.

From researching online, I understand this is most likely due to terminating null bytes however I don't grasp how I would resolve/get around that.

```
int8_t foo[size];
const char* const bar;

if(0 != strcmp((char *)foo, bar)){
   fail 
}
```

Expect results are `strcmp` returning 0 because both strings are the same when printing.

Actual outcome: returning fail.

Actual data: 5352A565712345657567565785658956581
When running `printf("Value of foo and bar: %s and %s", foo, bar)`, both variables return that data above.

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: We can't answer without knowing exactly what data is in the two variables.

Comment: If you want (strings of) characters, use `char`. If you want small integers, use `int8_t` or `uint8_t` (or `signed char` or `unsigned char`).

Comment: Added the data as requested.

Comment: What about non-printable content? Can you be sure there is none?

Comment: If it was about terminating 0 bytes, you should get one output longer than the other.

Comment: @Gerhardh that's where I get a bit confused (still quite new to C). How would I know if there is non-printable content, or is that a redundant question?

Comment: You could run the program in a debugger and inspect the memory content when  you enter that function.

Comment: Compare is failing because the 2 "strings" are not the same.  "because both strings are the same" is an incorrect conclusion on your part.  You need to post more evidence/code how you (errantly) concluded they are the same string.

Answer (score 0):

it is not enough to have :

```
int8_t foo[] = { 'a', 'b' };
```

to be able to do

```
if (strcmp(foo, "ab") == 0)
  puts("equals");
else
  puts("not equal");
```

because *strcmp* like a lot of other functions working on *char ** expect a null character signaling the end of the string.

What appends when *strcmp* goes after 'b' in *foo* is an undefined behavior

so

```
int8_t foo[] = { 'a', 'b', 0 };
```

is a candidate for `strcmp(foo, "ab")` thanks to the added null char allowing *strcmp* to not go out of *foo* in any cases

---

Note the same problem occurs if you do `printf("%s", foo);` in the first case, while a null char is not reach in the memory after the 'b' from *foo* the function *printf* will try to write the memory as characters, but this is an undefined behavior

Comment: Great answer, thank you for taking the time to make it quite understandable! Just a quick follow up question, foo, while initialized to int8_t foo[size], is passed into a function x(foo). This function populates the array from sqlite3 statements. How would I append a null terminator to foo after it's been populated with it's values?

Comment: Disregard the above comment, I appended the arrays with a null terminator 0 and still not working. However when I print foo and bar as hex numbers (%x) they are different. foo = vcd16a40 and bar = vcd169e0

Comment: @CianO'Shaughnessy the function _x_ has to put the null byte at the end, or it has for instance to return the number of bytes set to be able to add the null at the right position. However to mix string and array of byte is quite strange ;-)

Comment: @CianO'Shaughnessy how can you have 'v' in hexa ? `int8_t foo[] = { 'a', 'b', 0 }; printf("%d\n", strcmp(foo, "ab"));` will print 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to recreate this scenario despite getting warnings at compilation time.
What is the expected behavior?
Do you mean that the comparison is failing, or is the code failing to get into the `if` block?
If both arrays contain the same data, the `strcmp()` will return 0 and then the `if` block won't be executed.

I'm just trying to clarify. bruno's answer considering strcmp's behavior is also true.